# Concatenate three Float64 variables into one variable

Tags: python, pandas, string-concatenation

I have df that has many variables and I need to concatenate only 3 float variables of it:

```
    v1  v2  v3
0   2.0 NaN 1.0
1   1.0 1.0 1.0
2   NaN NaN 2.0
3   NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN 2.0

df.dtypes()

v1          float64
v2          float64
v3          float64
dtype: object
```

I need to concatenate all 3 variables into `df['concatenated']` and to have these result:

```
    v1  v2  v3  concatenated
0   2.0 NaN 1.0 2.0_NaN_1.0
1   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0_1.0_1.0
2   NaN NaN 2.0 NaN_NaN_2.0
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN_NaN_NaN
4   NaN NaN 2.0 NaN_NaN_2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the capitalization of your `NaN`s doesn't matter, this would be sufficient:

```
df['concatenated'] = df.astype(str).apply('_'.join,1)
>>> df
    v1   v2   v3 concatenated
0  2.0  NaN  1.0  2.0_nan_1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0_1.0_1.0
2  NaN  NaN  2.0  nan_nan_2.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  nan_nan_nan
4  NaN  NaN  2.0  nan_nan_2.0
```

If the capitalization matters, then you have to use `replace` beforehand:

```
df['concatenated'] = df.astype(str).replace('nan','NaN').apply('_'.join,1)
>>> df
    v1   v2   v3 concatenated
0  2.0  NaN  1.0  2.0_NaN_1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0_1.0_1.0
2  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN_NaN_2.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN_NaN_NaN
4  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN_NaN_2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but how to specify the 3 variables (v1,v2,v3) in your code as I am work with entire dataset and I need to add one more column of that combined 3 variables?Your solutions assumes that in my dataframe I only have 3 variables.

Comment: You can specify like this:  `df['concatenated'] = df[['v1','v2','v3']].astype(str).replace('nan','NaN').apply('_'.join,1)`